# ACCESS 2010 System Resource Exceeded

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My team were working with access 2000, where we have our MDB project. This application(ERP) could open around 20 access forms. After we decide migrate our entire system to Access 2010 to its new format, *.accdb; we are having this trouble with less memory, around 100mb nowadays.

Is there any workaround, any path i could follow to increase my access 2010 project memory limit.

Problem's Flow: We put login and password in the initial form, and start opening forms(form from access forms, literally). When around 10 forms, the memory used by acess 2010 reachs 107mb, and when we open the next form, the system crash with the following error: "3035 Description System resource exceeded"

Comment: Possibly you could think about redesigning the app so that it doesn't need to open so many forms at once.  Also are you certain that stopping "one more form" from opening actually leaves the application running.  Possibly one of your forms that is open already is hogging memory.

Comment: The application is very complex, and we cant limit the number of forms, because the clients dont wanna. We have been running this "one more form" test about a hundred times. And you are right, one opened form use the connection memory, where happens the memory limit problem.

Comment: We are getting back to access 2000, we couldnt solve the problem.

Comment: @DiegoGarciaVieira: Did you ever solve this issue? Or are you still on Access 2000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by 32 bit Access exceeding the 32 bit windows Virtual Memory limit of 2GB per app. I don't know why this issue does not crop up on Windows XP (didn't have time to test it).

You can track VM usage either through Performance Monitor or through code in the access app. You will see that as forms open the VM usage creeps up until access balks.

The solution is to switch to Access 64 bit on windows 64bit. Keep in mind that if you have external dll calls they need to be rewritten for 64 bit. Also ActiveX controls need to be 64 bit.

---

Code to track VM

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub GlobalMemoryStatus Lib "kernel32" (lpBuffer As MEMORYSTATUS)

Public Type MEMORYSTATUS
   dwLength As Long
   dwMemoryLoad As Long
   dwTotalPhys As Long
   dwAvailPhys As Long
   dwTotalPageFile As Long
   dwAvailPageFile As Long
   dwTotalVirtual As Long
   dwAvailVirtual As Long
End Type

Function ReturnVirtualMemory() As Long

    Dim Mem as MEMORYSTATUS

    Mem.dwLength = Len(Mem)
    GlobalMemoryStatus Mem

    ReturnVirtualMemory = Mem.dwTotalVirtual - Mem.dwAvailVirtual
End Function
```

Comment: This is really a solution, but we wont use it because we cant change user experience to repair our limitations. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This may help as did for me:
Activate system managed paging on all your drives. 
For this,

1. RightClick on 'My Computer' icon and select 'Properties',
2. Go to 'Advanced system settings'>Advanced>Settings>Advanced>Change,
3. Uncheck 'Automatically manage paging ...' and select all your drives one by one and set 'System managed size' for each.
4. Press [OK] and you're done.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A65U.png)

Comment: This worked great, I've been searching for the past week nonstop and cannot find the solution. Thanks for taking time to type your idea here.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the VM tracking code provided by Mint, I've made a sort of 'Early warning' system for my application that warns you when the VM is approaching a point where it'll start causing problems and recommend a reboot.  It's slightly annoying, but until someone comes up with a better solution to 32-Bit Office running in a 64-Bit OS environment, it'll have to do.

**ReturnVM:** Returns the Virtual Memory usage in GB, triggers alert if it's over 1.425GB.  I've found that this works for my application giving as much time between restarts while still allowing some leeway to finish work before restarting.  Feel free to adjust as needed.

**os_Restart:** Writes a batch file that kills the active Access process, deletes the leftover laccdb file and restarts the application (provided everything's on the user's desktop).  After writing the file, it executes the batch.  Another function deletes this file on application start.

**TempVars!tv_WinUID** = Environ("USERNAME")

```
Function ReturnVM() As Double

    Dim Mem As MEMORYSTATUS
    Dim Result As Integer

    Mem.dwLength = Len(Mem)
    GlobalMemoryStatus Mem

    ReturnVM = Format((Mem.dwTotalVirtual - Mem.dwAvailVirtual) / 1073741824, "0.000")

    Debug.Print ReturnVM & " GB of VM used."

    If (ReturnVM >= 1.425) Then
      DoEvents
      Result = MsgBox("Office Virtual Memory usage is approaching the pre-set limit." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "To prevent a possible crash, please click 'OK' to restart immediately." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You may click 'Cancel' to finish what you're working on, but if you do, please restart the application as soon as possible.", vbOKCancel)
      If (Result = vbOK) Then
        os_Restart
      End If
    End If

End Function

Public Function os_Restart()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim BatchContents As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\" & TempVars!tv_WinUID & "\Desktop\RestartAccess.bat")

    BatchContents = "@echo Restarting Application..." & vbCrLf & _
                    "@echo off" & vbCrLf & _
                    "taskkill /f /im MSACCESS.EXE" & vbCrLf & _
                    "ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul" & vbCrLf & _
                    "del " & Chr(34) & "C:\Users\" & TempVars!tv_WinUID & "\Desktop\Application.laccdb" & Chr(34) & vbCrLf & _
                    "start " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "C:\Users\" & TempVars!tv_WinUID & "\Desktop\Application.accdb" & Chr(34)

    DoEvents
    'Debug.Print BatchContents
    oFile.WriteLine BatchContents
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

    Call Shell("C:\users\" & TempVars!tv_WinUID & "\Desktop\RestartAccess.bat")

End Function
```

Comment: Really nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

After months of frustration I have found a cause and a solution for this in both Access 2010 and Access 2013. Having Skype loaded in the background when running the program was causing the "System resource exceeded error" during both large queries and compact and repair.

If you still have problems run in windows xp compatibility mode