# "System resource exceeded" Error from ODBC MS Access Driver when executing a SELECT query in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have written a python program that uses pyodbc to interact with a Microsoft Access database. The database contains a table with measurements of wells (about 6.3 million).

The program's basic work flow is to get a list of chemicals. Then for every chemical it will use a select query to find every well in the table that has data for that chemical. For each of the wells it will use another select query to fetch a data set which contains all of the measurements for the well of the chemical.

Once it has this data set, it calculates some statistics on it which it uses to create a new row for the chemical and well pair the data set was for. Each of these new rows are then output into a new database table.

Note that, I am using python's multiprocessing package to allow the program to use more of the cpu's capacity. The program always has one consumer process that takes the data out of a queue and inserts it into a new separate db from the input data base. Then the program has a variable amount of producer processes that take chemicals from a queue, process them, and add there data to the output queue.

When I run the program on chemical lists that are about long it will sometimes error:

```
Starting: 01027
Failed on 01027 when selecting wells for chemical.
Failed. Wells processed: 371693
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrutledge\Desktop\well_trend_processor_python_2016\python_processor\well_trends.py", line 230, in read_data_sets_into_queue
    raise e
```

This happens at least once (sometimes more) for a list of 96 chemicals, but not for ten or less, not sure where the cut off is. The intended cause of this error message seems to be running queries that take too much memory, but this does not seem to be the result here. One reason being, the chemicals that it errors on are not consistent between attempts. Furthermore, if I run a smaller list of chemicals that includes failed chemicals, then they process without errors.

The problem seems to be happening when I am selecting the wells for a chemical:

```
# Find each well that has samples of this chemical
wells_cursor = measurement_db_chemical.cursor()
sql_string = """SELECT DISTINCT {0}.Well_ID, PSCODE, STAID, Status
                FROM {0}
                LEFT JOIN {1}
                ON {0}.Well_ID = {1}.Well_ID
                WHERE STORE_NUM = ?""".format(
                    well_records_table_name, well_sites_table_name)
try:
    wells_cursor.execute(sql_string, chemical.STORE_NUM)
# Close db connection if error, outer try will close connection
except Exception, e:
    print ('Process {}: Failed on {} when selecting wells for chemical.'.format(process_number, chemical.STORE_NUM))
            raise e
```

Although, as said before this SQL query executes without problems way more often than it causes errors, so it does not seem like there is an error in the SQL. However, this is the most intensive query the program makes so it makes sense that it would be the one to exceed resources.

This problem persists if I remove the inserting part of the program. This way it does everything it normally would but, after it is done calculating statistics it does not insert them into a new table.

I thought it may have been cause by leave the connection to the db open for too long and somehow it was accumulating garbage memory or something. This lead me to make the python program open a new connection to the db for each chemical, and then close it when it is done processing that chemical. However, the problem persists.

Notably, total memory usage never goes over 60% no matter how I run it so I do not think that is the problem.

Also the size of the database is less than 800 mb which is no where near the 2 gb size limit for MS Access databases.

I ran the program with only one process and it worked. This lead me to think that although anyone select query may not be too resource expensive for the ODBC driver to handle, multiple really expensive queries executed at the same time and may cause the driver to reach its resource limit. I have now modified the program and added python RLocks while any SQL queries are executing in the data base, so that only one program can read from the db at a time, which would eliminate this problem. Yesterday a run with four processes completed successfully and I thought this fixed the problem, but today it still having the same error in the select well query, even when I run it with only one process.

(I posted this as an answer when I thought it was a solution and have now deleted it)

Also not that when using this method cpu usage never goes over 80% because the processes have to wait for one another to query, and it still errors. Meaning the ODBC driver's interface with the db must have some coded limit on usage.

What do you think is causing this error and how should I approach fixing it?

If you would like to see more code let me know which part (there is lots of it).

Comment: Can you post full traceback as *System Resource Exceeded* does not appear in post? Also, this is an MS Access error, not a Python error. Usually this message involves complex queries, handling of NULL values, reserve words, and syntax items.

Comment: Also, as test, can you run same operation inside MSAccess.exe (if you have the Office program available)? And a `DISTINCT` with `LEFT JOIN` is not too optimized.

Comment: @Parfait I have ran the well select query in Access and it works fine. I am not sure how to run the whole operation: running 100 Select queries in series. Other than doing it manually and that would take more than an hour of clicking. Besides the query has worked for every chemical through the pyodbc interface, it just doesn't all work at once.

Comment: @Parfait You said the `SELECT DISTINCT` `LEFT JOIN` isn't well optimized. How would I optimize it?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19550367/2144390)? Are you running 32-bit Python? If so, is switching to 64-bit Python (and 64-bit Access Database Engine) a possibility? Also, are you sure that running multiple processes is really going  to speed up your application?

Comment: @GordThompson From smaller successful runs splitting up processes more than halves the time to process the data(1hr -> 24 min). I am running 32-bit python, unfortunately I do not believe there is a 64 bit MS Access ODBC driver. That posts mention of a 2 gb limit may be my problem. Yet, I am now running it without multiple processes so that it just executes the select queries in sequence and does nothing else. It seems like this would never get to 2gb because it is just executing small queries one after another, but it is still having the same problem.

Comment: @GordThompson Actually there are [64 bit drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39358). I will try those now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, MS Access' *System Resources Exceeded* is a somewhat ambiguous message which can pertain to actual CPU resources, network environment, or an inefficient SQL query or VBA module that impairs the engine's performance.

However, your SQL can be optimized. Consider replacing the `DISTINCT` clause with an aggregate query using `GROUP BY` in the well query. `DISTINCT` is a usual SQL performance drain across most RDMS, requiring a full resultset sort to remove duplicates. Further, `DISTINCT` tends to be an ad-hoc fix that compensates for an inadequate database design or planned process:

```
sql_string = """SELECT {0}.Well_ID, PSCODE, STAID, Status
                FROM {0}
                LEFT JOIN {1} ON {0}.Well_ID = {1}.Well_ID
                WHERE STORE_NUM = ?
                GROUP BY {0}.Well_ID, PSCODE, STAID, Status"""\
                .format(well_records_table_name, well_sites_table_name)
```

Should other areas trigger the error, best practices in table design and query handling may help. Therefore, check for other issues including complex nested subqueries; functions in `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses; use of very wide tables (a sign to normalize in one-to-many/many-to-many relationships); and large transactions like make-table/append/update of big queries which Access saves a copy of resultset for rollback needs (sometimes reaching 2 GB size).

Access DB Tips

1. Try [compacting &
   repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2)
   once in a while to avoid bloating and refresh the database
   statistics for query optimizer. Though your database is 800 MB,
   databases are known to expand during operations and for large transactions as mentioned above can reach file limits.
2. Use indexing in tables in addition to primary/composite keys. In Table design view, you can select individual fields as index in *Field Properties* section or use SQL's [`CREATE INDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177891(v=office.12).aspx). And ideally, join tables by such indices.
3. Save stored queries in Access which are pre-compiled and optimized to best plan and call the named objects in Python `SELECT * FROM Query1` instead of the engine running it on the fly. This is a usual discussion of VBA Queries vs Stored Queries in MS Access. Even use temp tables for calculations or migrate to Python's [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data frames for analysis.
4. Try splitting the backend database into multiple databases which reduces individual file size. Recall Access can link to other Access files using linked tables (which Python can access) even server level RDMS such as SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.
5. Always heed [Access's limitations](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/access_specification.php) such as table columns, query joins, file/table size. Access after all is a file level RDMS and not server RDMS whose infrastructure is open-ended.

Comment: I will accept this answer because the problem of this error message definitely seems like it has many causes and this answers seems to give some good practices about approaching most causes.

Comment: Curious though, did the `GROUP BY` help compared to the `DISTINCT clause`?

Comment: For those curious what solved my problem, it was probably a variety of changes. I think the biggest one was redesigning the program's flow so that only one process read from the data base at a time. This unfortunately makes the program much slower because reading from access is slow compared to all the other operations. However, it does seem to limit the resources the connection uses so that it never cause any problems. I also made some other small changes with optimizing quires and using the minimal amount of connections and cursors.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not specifically test the change form `GROUP BY` to `DISTINCT`. I think the biggest change was the one mentioned in the comment about. However, if it is a more optimized query, then it probably helped some.