# Multiple OleDbCommands producing System Resource Exceeded

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

So basically I have a C# project, that iterates through every student (300 students) within a table called `Student` within a Microsoft Access 2016 database. In a single iteration for a single student by using other tables like `Mathematics`, `Reading` that have a 1-to-1 relationship with the `Student` table, to grab the data that belongs to that student.

```
                try
            {
                OleDbCommand allStudents = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [NSN]"
                 + " FROM [Student]; ");

                allStudents.Connection = conn;
                OleDbDataAdapter allData = new OleDbDataAdapter(allStudents);
                DataTable allTable = new DataTable();
                allData.Fill(allTable);

                foreach (DataRow dr in allTable.Rows)
                {
                    string NSN = dr["NSN"].ToString();

                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * "
                        + "FROM (((([Student] s "
                        + "INNER JOIN [Student Extra] se ON se.[NSN] = s.[NSN]) "
                        + "INNER JOIN [Reading] r ON r.[NSN] = s.[NSN])"
                        + "INNER JOIN [Writing] w ON w.[NSN] = s.[NSN])"
                        + "INNER JOIN [Mathematics] m ON m.[NSN] = s.[NSN]) "

                        + "WHERE s.[NSN] = '" + NSN + "'; ");
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    OleDbDataAdapter daa = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
                    daa.Fill(dtt);


                    foreach (DataRow drr in dtt.Rows)
                    {
                        firstName = drr["Preferred Name"].ToString();
                        gender = drr["Gender"].ToString();
                        room = drr["Room Number"].ToString();
                        NSAchieve = drr["National Standard Achieve"].ToString();
                        NSProgress = drr["National Standard Progress"].ToString();
```

The above code is only a snippet of the code I have, but this is basically where the function will start.

By using this data, I want to be able to go through several `SELECT` statements for other tables and compare them and produce a calculated value.

```
Dictionary<string, OleDbCommand> d = new Dictionary<string, OleDbCommand>(); 
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Achievement Statement]"
        + " FROM [National Standard Codes]"
        + " WHERE [National Standard Code] = '" + readingNSAchievementCode + "'; ");
        d["readingNSAchievementOTJ"] = cmd;

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [" + NSAchieve + "]"
       + " FROM [Reading National Standards]"
       + " WHERE [Assessment] = '" + readingFinalAssessment + "'; ");
        d["readingNSAchievementComp"] = cmd;

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Timeframe]"
        + " FROM [Reading Statements]"
        + " WHERE [Year Code] = '" + NSProgress + "'; ");
        d["readingNSProgressTimeframe"] = cmd;
```

There are several more commands, (approx <150). I use a `Dictionary` to store my Commands, and then execute the commands in a `FOREACH` loop.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, OleDbCommand> pair in d)
        {
            try
            {
                string v = pair.Key;
                OleDbCommand dbCmd = pair.Value;


                dbCmd.Connection = conn;
                OleDbDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                readingDict[v] = reader.GetString(0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error at " + pair.Key + "\n\n Here is message " + e);
            }
        }
```

After executing and getting my value, I want to store my data into another table called `Calculated`.

```
            string insert1 = "INSERT INTO [Calculated] (";
        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = createDictionary(NSN);
        int len = dict.Count / 2;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
        {
            string field = pair.Key;
            string value = pair.Value;

            if (i == (len - 1))
            {
                insert1 += "[" + field + "])";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                insert1 += "[" + field + "], ";
            }

            i++;
        }
        insert1 += " VALUES (";
        i = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
        {
            string field = pair.Key;
            string value = pair.Value;

            if (i == len - 1)
            {
                insert1 += "'" +  value + "')";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                insert1 += "'" + value + "', ";
            }

            i++;
        }
```

I build my `INSERT INTO` query, and then I execute using an `OleDbCommand`. This needs to repeat 300 times, but for development purposes currently I only have 5 students in my `Student` table. However when executing after the 4th student it will always consistently give me an error `System Resources Exceeded` always at a specific `OleDbCommand`. I have tested each command separately, so there is no issue with the way the `OleDbCommand`s are written.

I have tried searching on here, and tried to encase the first code snippet in a `using` statement, using `using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))` but as I am still a novice at `C#`, I am unable to produce a solution.

Comment: See [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). **Use parameters!!**. Also make sure you are closing the connection consintently (use `using` blocks). You should probably rethingk the overall strategy, try to get as much related data out of the db per call (ie. related tables for a student) and then batch that as well (ie. 50 stundents and related data per DB call). Also using actual POCO objects (pure entity) and populating those with a data reader is much more efficient than datatables.

Comment: See also [ACCESS 2010 System Resource Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20021521/1260204)